# OpenLDAP replication fails, "syncrepl_entry: rid=666 be_modify failed (20)"

Tags: replication, openldap

I've configured a second host to replicate the main LDAP server via syncrepl in the `slapd.conf`:

```
syncrepl rid=666 
        provider=ldaps://my-main-server.com 
        type=refreshAndPersist 
        searchBase="dc=Staff,dc=my-main-server,dc=com" 
        filter="(objectClass=*)" 
        scope=sub 
        schemachecking=off 
        bindmethod=simple 
        binddn="cn=repadmin,dc=my-main-server,dc=com" 
        credentials=mypassword
```

When I restart `slapd`, it writes to `/var/log/debug`

```
Jun 11 15:48:33 cluster-mn-04 slapd[29441]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.9 (Mar 31 2009 07:18:37) $ ^Ibuildd@yellow:/build/buildd/openldap2.3-2.4.9/debian/build/servers/slapd 
Jun 11 15:48:34 cluster-mn-04 slapd[29442]: slapd starting 
Jun 11 15:48:34 cluster-mn-04 slapd[29442]: null_callback : error code 0x14 
Jun 11 15:48:34 cluster-mn-04 slapd[29442]: syncrepl_entry: rid=666 be_modify failed (20) 
Jun 11 15:48:34 cluster-mn-04 slapd[29442]: do_syncrepl: rid=666 quitting
```

I've looked into the sources for the return code and found only

```
#define LDAP_TYPE_OR_VALUE_EXISTS       0x14
```

in `include/ldap.h`. Anyway, I don't quite get what the error message means.

Can you help me debugging this problem and figure out why the LDAP replication doesn't work? I've managed to put a "manual" copy via `slapcat` and `slapadd` into the database, but I'd like to sync automatically.

**UPDATE:**
"Solved" by removing `/var/lib/ldap/*` and re-importing the database with `slapadd`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that slapd have the right to write in dirs ? Usually, after a from scratch insert, you must change the owner of directories.

Comment: what directories exactly do you mean?

Comment: On my debian, the datas are stored in /var/lib/ldap, which should be owned by openldap:openldap. All files in the dir should have the same owner.

Comment: yeah, it's the same on my ubuntu box.